# How to inject adapter with hilt

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dagger-hilt

I have a complete recyclerView example, now I want to use hilt inject the ItemListAdapter of this example to my ItemListFragment. But it seems something that can not be done if I still want the way of hilt.

```
class ItemListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: ItemListViewModel by viewModels()
    private var adapter: ItemListAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentItemListBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        adapter =
            ItemListAdapter(
                ItemListOnClickListener { itemId ->
                    viewModel.onItemClicked(itemId)
                })
        binding.itemList.adapter = adapter

        return binding.root
    }
}

class ItemListAdapter(private val onClickListener: ItemListOnClickListener):
    ListAdapter<Item, ItemListAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        ItemListDiffCallback()
    ) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    class ViewHolder constructor(private val binding: ListItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Item) {
            binding.item = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}

class ItemListDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
}

class ItemListOnClickListener(val clickListener: (itemID: String) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(itemID: String) = clickListener(itemID)
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? You don't need to inject everything, everywhere.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I don't know is it need to do this.

Comment: Sir @BartekLipinski is it bad practice to inject adapter this way or not inject it at all?

Comment: @ELTEGANIMOHAMEDHAMMADGABIR that's entirely opinion-based. If you ask me if I do injections like that in my code, the answer is no. But who the hell am I to tell you how to write your own code 

Comment: @BartekLipinski okay, I will follow your approach. thanks for your humble

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want? Can you check if this works and satisfies your need.

**NOTE**: I expect that you did setup annotations well so hilt was setup and works correctly in your project (ex: annotating `ItemListFragment` fragment with `@AndroidEntryPoint`, etc...)

I had such case, and I thought rather than feeding the callback in the constructor, I should provide it through a setter method of the adapter.

For `ItemListAdapter`, we can make a property of type `ItemListOnClickListener`, and provide `setOnClickListener` setter method.
That's it, now you can make use of `onClickListener` in `ViewHolder` (Now `ItemListAdapter` constructor is a no-arg one, and *Hilt* is able to provide a binding for it for your case):

```java
@Singleton
class ItemListAdapter @Inject constructor():
    ListAdapter<Item, ItemListAdapter.ViewHolder>(ItemListDiffCallback()) {
    
    private var onClickListener: ItemListOnClickListener? = null

    ...

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: ItemListOnClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    inner class ViewHolder constructor(private val binding: ListItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Item) {
            binding.item = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()

            // Use `onClickListener` when binding `OnClickListener` callback
            binding.view.setOnClickListener(v -> onClickListener?.onClick(...))
        }
    }
}
```

For `ItemListFragment`, you don't need to construct an adapter, because Hilt will be able to provide you with one. All you have to do is provide a listener through `setOnClickListener` method of this adapter:

```java
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ItemListFragment: Fragment() {

    @Inject
    var adapter: ItemListAdapter? = null

    private val viewModel: ItemListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentItemListBinding.inflate(inflater)

        ...

        adapter?.setOnClickListener(
                ItemListOnClickListener { 
                        itemId -> viewModel.onItemClicked(itemId) 
                }
        )

        binding.itemList.adapter = adapter

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, after trying the hilt for adapter I think it might need more complex operation than without it.

Comment: If ItemListAdapter have an interface like clickListener, ItemListFragment implement that interface and ItemListFragment pass the instance of interface in constructor, How to inject adapter? with hilt

Comment: @MohammadSultanAlNahiyan, my apology I don't develop Android these days to help you more with the question.

Comment: `@Singleton` is very bad for adapter

Answer (score 4):

**Answer Feb 2021**

This is the easiest answer.

In Module class

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAdapter(): MyAdapter = MyAdapter()
}
```

In Adapter class

```
private var onItemClickListener: ((RestaurantX) -> Unit)? = null
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (RestaurantX) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

Then put this line inside `view.setOnClckListener`

```
onItemClickListener?.let {
   it(restaurantX)
}
```

In Activity/Fragment

```
 @Inject
 lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
```

And then inside a method

```
myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {it->
            //do whatever you like
}
```

If you still have confussion [here is full source code](https://github.com/vikskod/Restaurant-List)

Comment: source code not working, existing api key not working unable to create new api key

Comment: code look clean & good, can you check your API key or give sample json

Comment: According to the official docs. Normally you use providers mainly for the classes from third-party libraries or the classes we don't own. I think simple construct-inject for the adapter.

Comment: After implementing this I come to know that setOnItemClickListener is not working. Can you please see it?

Comment: This is wrong. 1) You shouldn't mark the `MyAdapter` as `@Singleton`. You need normal instance. 2) You don't need to create it through module. Just mark the `MyAdapter` constructor with `@Inject` annotation. 3) If your adapter doesn't need any dependencies (as here you have no arguments in your constructor), you can create the `MyAdapter` instance yourself in the Fragment and don't need to go through Hilt at all.